You do not have permission to insert OmniScriptSavedSession Error
We've created a Omniscript form for guest user. But when we try to save the progress it's throwing error 'You do not have permission to insert OmniScriptSavedSession'.

According to this Salesforce documentation article Gettin Error in Omniscripts for Gues Users : "You do not have Permission to Insert vlocity_ins__OmniScriptInstance__c" I tried getting guest user with OmniscriptSavedSession access.

I was able to get (2) permission for the object via a guest user assigned permission set.
But (1) I don't see an option to create a sharing rule for the Guest user.

Has anyone received this error before? Any workaround tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Note: There is no way I can add a guest user to a public group here, it shows only internal users here,

Update 10/10/2024: Provided Public Read-only access in sharing setting, but still getting the same error.


Omniscript Objects are annoying to properly configure and errors are not intuitive sometimes.
If you want to debug the issue then I advise to use process of elimination and add all Omniscript related objects in OWD as External Visible and then check what's actually missing.
Also make sure that you also grant Object/Field Level access with Profile/Permission Set
From what I remember you also can't use Save Later without OmniScript license on the user.
By the way, how would guest user access Save Later? There is only one Guest user, so the form will be shared between everyone

Thanks @ytiq ,I tried setting access for this object: Create/Read for guest site user, but no luck. I've logged a SF support case. Will update here when I hear back. To answer your question, so guest user can receive a link to click and retrieve the form later,, and also receive an email with the link to use later.

Also I gave All omni objects public read-only access, but still getting the same error. I wonder if I have missed some config. for the guest user here. :/

Try assigning Permission Set License for OmniStudio to Guest User it might be another reason

I agree and yes the Permission set license is also already assigned @ytiq, It's only this object is not having the share to guest user, other omni objects do have the option to share for guest user.

ok, thank you. So it seems you can't use save later for Guest, because every unauthorized user will have access to it.

As per SF Support as of 10/Oct/2024 This seems not possible with standard Omni Object unfortunately.


Please, review the documentation below:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_configure_save_options.htm&type=5
At the Note it clarifies that ... "... Guest users and Experience
Cloud users can't use Omniscript Saved Sessions because security
policies prevent them from retaining ownership of records they
create."

